# When I use storm scheduler, can one host be scheduled for two times?

Tags: apache-storm, scheduler, trident

For example

```html
        topology.newStream("process", new RawDataSpout())
                .parallelismHint(1)
                .shuffle()
                .each(new Fields("frameID"), new RawToRgb(), new Fields("frameIDRawToRgbCompleted"))
                .parallelismHint(1)
                .shuffle()
                .each(new Fields("frameID", "frameIDRawToRgbCompleted"), new StereoInit(), new Fields("frameIDInitCompleted"))
                .parallelismHint(1)
                .setMemoryLoad(6144)
                .shuffle()
                .each(new Fields("frameID", "frameIDRawToRgbCompleted", "frameIDInitCompleted"), new StereoRing(), new Fields("frameIDRingCompleted"))
                .parallelismHint(1)
                .shuffle()
                .each(new Fields("frameID", "frameIDRawToRgbCompleted", "frameIDInitCompleted", "frameIDRingCompleted"), new Rendering(), new Fields("frameIDRenderingCompleted"))
                .parallelismHint(1)
                .setMemoryLoad(6144);
```

As the code above, can one host run both StereoInit and Rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But there is no guarantee by default.

I you want to enforce this, you need to provide a custom scheduler.
Example: https://github.com/xumingming/storm-lib/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/DemoScheduler.java